# error when trying to retrieve class name with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
var allRows = $('.myclass');
...
allRows.each(function() {   //now search through all the rows
          var className = this.attr("class");
          ...    
        });
```

I am getting an error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'
```

What is wronte with my code? I did a console.log on the allRows and it is a jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this,

```
 var className = $(this).attr("class");// attr is jquery function
 console.log(className);
```

**Full code**

```
var allRows = $('.myclass');
...
allRows.each(function() {   //now search through all the rows
    var className = $(this).attr("class");// change this to $(this) here
    console.log(className);            
});
```

Comment: of course, thanks! attr() is jquery method, so of course you have to first pass this to jquery.

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```
var className = $(this).attr("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `this` to `$(this)`:

```
 var className = $(this).attr("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `className`

```
var allRows = $('.myclass');
allRows.each(function () { //now search through all the rows
    var className = this.className;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using "this" correctly. Below is given the correct way:-

```
    var allRows = $('.myclass');
       ...
    $(allRows).each(function() {   //now search through all the rows
       var className = $(this).attr("class");
       ...    
    });
```